# Azure functions & Powershell: get response in plain JSON

Tags: json, powershell, azure, azure-functions

Trying out some new features in Azure; Azure Functions running Powershell. One thing I'm struggling with for a while: I cannot get the output in plain JSON, instead in seems formatted and includes escape characters and is messed up double quoting.

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "head",
        "trace"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "res",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.ps1:

```
$ApiURI="http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=ymml&format=JSON"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiURI
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $Result
```

Results in following response:

```
"\r\n\r\nAltimeter         : 1015\r\nCloud-List        : {FEW 035}\r\nDewpoint          : 11\r\nFlight-Rules      : VFR\r\nOther-List        : {}\r\nRaw-Report        : YMML 210900Z 17010KT 9999 FEW035 19/11 Q1015 NOSIG\r\nRemarks           : NOSIG\r\nRemarks-Info      : \r\nRunway-Vis-List   : {}\r\nStation           : YMML\r\nTemperature       : 19\r\nTime              : 210900Z\r\nUnits             : @{Altimeter=hPa; Altitude=ft; Temperature=C; Visibility=m; \r\n                    Wind-Speed=kt}\r\nVisibility        : 9999\r\nWind-Direction    : 170\r\nWind-Gust         : \r\nWind-Speed        : 10\r\nWind-Variable-Dir : {}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

But what I expect is something like:

```
{
  "Altimeter": "1016", 
  "Cloud-List": [], 
  "Dewpoint": "12", 
  "Flight-Rules": "VFR", 
  "Other-List": [], 
  "Raw-Report": "YMML 210930Z 17011KT CAVOK 18/12 Q1016 NOSIG", 
  "Remarks": "NOSIG", 
  "Remarks-Info": {}, 
  "Runway-Vis-List": [], 
  "Station": "YMML", 
  "Temperature": "18", 
  "Time": "210930Z", 
  "Units": {
    "Altimeter": "hPa", 
    "Altitude": "ft", 
    "Temperature": "C", 
    "Visibility": "m", 
    "Wind-Speed": "kt"
  }, 
  "Visibility": "9999", 
  "Wind-Direction": "170", 
  "Wind-Gust": "", 
  "Wind-Speed": "11", 
  "Wind-Variable-Dir": []
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you got that result, since `Invoke-RestMethod` store the data in the `ResponseData` property.
When you use `Invoke-RestMethod` it will convert the json data to a Powershell Object. In your run.ps1 it looks like you are going to save the PS Object to a file, not the JSON data.

If you are not going to modify the JSON data, it's really no use to convert it to a PSObject. So you could use `Invoke-webrequest` instead.

But in case you want to modify it.

```
$uri = "http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=ymml&format=JSON"

$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri

#Get the result and convert it back to JSON
$Result = $request.responseData | ConvertTo-Json
$Result | Out-File .\data.json -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: The goal is to process the JSON data so I'd like to have it converted into an object. But this is not the issue, because same unwanted result when piping a JSON string directly without doing a call. Your code sample works when executed as plain ps, but when deployed in an Azure function with output piped to the function's http response `$res` it has same results. I'd guess this pipe is responsible for this formatting somehow and I'm looking for a way to prevent this behavior..

Comment: Clear! The data was not JSON anymore because of `Invoke-RestMethod` parsing it into an object. So needed the conversion back by `ConvertTo-Json`.

Answer (score 0):

@David - Yes, the following works for me in Azure Functions.

a. `run.ps1` file content

```
$ApiURI="http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=ymml&format=JSON"
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiURI | ConvertTo-Json
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $Result
```

b. Request result both in Azure Functions Portal and Postman.

```
{
  "Altimeter": "1016",
  "Cloud-List": [
    [
      "FEW",
      "016"
    ]
  ],
  "Dewpoint": "13",
  "Flight-Rules": "VFR",
  "Other-List": [],
  "Raw-Report": "YMML 212100Z 28005KT 9999 FEW016 15/13 Q1016 NOSIG",
  "Remarks": "NOSIG",
  "Remarks-Info": {},
  "Runway-Vis-List": [],
  "Station": "YMML",
  "Temperature": "15",
  "Time": "212100Z",
  "Units": {
    "Altimeter": "hPa",
    "Altitude": "ft",
    "Temperature": "C",
    "Visibility": "m",
    "Wind-Speed": "kt"
  },
  "Visibility": "9999",
  "Wind-Direction": "280",
  "Wind-Gust": "",
  "Wind-Speed": "05",
  "Wind-Variable-Dir": []
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the working sample; also works for me. And yes, indeed, I overlooked the Convert-ToJson as David already suggested.